# Different behavior between SessionTempDataProvider and CookieTempDataProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-4, tempdata

The short version of all this is that I'm using TempData to store feedback messages and after switching to using CookieTempDataProvider they don't show up when using the a PRG pattern, but if I revert back to SessionTempDataProvider they do.

In my MVC4 application I have a pattern of writing an alert message to the temp data for displaying on the screen after a successful Create/Update or when something goes wrong on certain pages and I need to show a failure message. For example...

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(PeopleEditFormModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = model.ObjectId });
    try
    {
        var person = personService.UpdatePerson(model); // personService is set via DI in constructor
        TempData["message"] = "Person successfully updated.";
        TempData["messageType"] = "success"
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = person.ObjectId });
    }
    catch (DomainException ex)
    {
        //For putting business logic errors in the ModelState
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id = model.ObjectId});
    }
}
```

I have a partial view called by my _Layout.cshtml file that is basically a placeholder DIV element (plus some js) that gets filled with my feedback message, and this works fine.

[image: UpdateFeedback]

Now this works by default but TempData relies on the session and I'd like to disable it if possible and use a different implementation of the TempDataProvider to get around not having a session. I have to use a different TempDataProvier because if I disable the session without changing the imlementation of TempData, the first time I try to use it I'll get an InvalidOperationException stating

> The SessionStateTempDataProvider class requires session state to be
>   enabled.

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

I've registered a new component with my Dependency Injector, StructureMap, and it looks like this.

```
//I have tried this with and without the HttpContextScoped()
For<ITempDataProvider>().HttpContextScoped().Use<CookieTempDataProvider>();
For<HttpContextBase>().HttpContextScoped().Use(x => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

<s>I should mention my implementation of the CookieTempDataProvider [is from here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/CookieTempDataProvider.cs)</s>
Apparently it's been removed.

Now, This solves the exception when I try to use TempData now but my feedback doesn't show up. I thought maybe I broke something in my efforts so I commented out my DI lines and changed my session state mode back to `InProc`, and tested it. My feedback shows up as expected (after restarting IISExpress). I uncomment my injection lines, change session state to `Off`, and I'm back to no feedback.

I did some further testing and found that if I do the following in my action I get no message

```
TempData["message"] = "Person successfully updated.";
TempData["messageType"] = "success"
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = person.ObjectId });
```

But if I ignore the PRG pattern, and instead do this then I see my feedback.

```
TempData["message"] = "Person successfully updated.";
TempData["messageType"] = "success"
return View("Edit", person);
```

So my question is, is there a flaw with the commonly accepted CookieTempDataProvider or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809379/asp-net-mvc-tempdata-in-browser-cookie

Comment: I've looked at that question (as well as a few others) and also searched Google but none of the issues seemed to be related to my problem of inconstant behavior when applying PRG pattern. I had assumed that the CookieTempDataProvider included with the MvcContrib (which I believe is what that source is for) library would be fully functional but I wanted to verify if it was the provider or my usage of it that was giving this behavior before I abandoned it in favor of trying to re-invent the wheel. I can't imagine I'm the only person to encounter this problem?

Comment: I'm using the exact same pattern, but I use this implementation of the cookietempdataprovider: https://github.com/brockallen/CookieTempData
Works fine for me.