# ASP.Net MVC - TempData session problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The WebFarm we are using doesn't supports Session. We are in a requirement to pass Data during redirects. How to do this without TempData dictionary since TempData uses Session inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own TempData provider and store it in cookies. See [ASP.NET MVC Store TempData in Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800290/asp-net-mvc-store-tempdata-in-cookie) Or you could have a base-class Controller that looks for a hidden input and hydrates objects / state and persists it to / from it each http request.

Note that TempData only persists between two controller actions.

Edit:

You could use the same example and write a provider that serializes to a DB ... or ... even to disk. Shoot, for that matter, you could even roll an entire custom replacement for Session. You'd create a session factory class and store your custom session objects via a key in some static collection. Then you'd track that session key either through cookies or via hidden input as stated above.

Comment: That's a good solution.But if my object size is huge then it will be a problem. Cookies allow maximum size 4 kb.In that case can you please give a good solution ? Can we use Velocity like cache providers ?

Comment: I liked what you said about just creating our own class to deal with it.  I created my own Dictionary<string, object> I stored data to, in a public class I could import with a `using` statement to bring in its namespace when I needed it.  This should work in any case when TempData, ViewData, Session, and Cookies don't.

Answer (score 0):

This was a very very useful question to learn more in MVC. Though I got some question like why Microsoft is assuming that people will know TempData uses session.

I got problem with uploading objects more than 4kb. For that our architect suggessted to split that object and save them in chunks in Cookies. I used the code from below blog to split the serialized string of the object.

http://lukencode.com/2010/04/21/split-string-into-array-of-chunks/

So split the cookie in the SaveTempData method and collect them into single string in LoadTempData. Thats it problem solved.

But I using a distributed caching technology like NVElocity is always better .

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that looks like this:

```
public class GlobalStorage
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> Device = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

Store:

```
GlobalStorage.Device.Add("myKey", mydata);
```

Retrieve:

```
string mydata = GlobalStorage.Device["myKey"].ToString();
```